# Rearranging multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, pyrocms

I have an array that I need to rearange a bit.
I am building a voice server status widget for pyrocms.

- I use for querying the voice server -> https://github.com/Austinb/GameQ
- I use for the template -> https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsrender

whit a static table i haven created this !
www.i.stack.imgur.com/4a3Am.png

I get an array return and it looks like this.:

```
Array (
"Ventrilo" => Array (
    "name" => "The Evil Teddys",
    "phonetic" => "The Evil Teddys",
    "comment" => "",
    "auth" => "1",
    "maxclients" => "20",
    "voicecodec" => "0,GSM 6.10",
    "voiceformat" => "3,44 KHz, 16 bit",
    "uptime" => "25799604",
    "platform" => "Linux-i386",
    "version" => "3.0.3",
    "channelcount" => "7",
    "teams" => Array (
        "0" => Array (
                "cid" => "846",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "<TET>",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "1" => Array (
                "cid" => "847",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "#ISOLATIECEL",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "2" => Array (
                "cid" => "848",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "Relax Take It Easy",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "3" => Array (
                "cid" => "849",
                "pid" => "846",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "Foodfightkitchen",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "4" => Array (
                "cid" => "850",
                "pid" => "846",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "WOW",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "5" => Array (
                "cid" => "851",
                "pid" => "849",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "Bad Company",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "6" => Array(
                "cid" => "852",
                "pid" => "850",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "The G Channel",
                "comm" => ""
            )
    ),
    "clientcount" => "3",
    "players" => Array (
        "0" => Array (
                "admin" => "1",
                "cid" => "846",
                "phan" => "0",
                "ping" => "18",
                "sec" => "345345",
                "name" => "Shorty*",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "1" => Array (
                "admin" => "1",
                "cid" => "851",
                "phan" => "0",
                "ping" => "20",
                "sec" => "11988",
                "name" => "Swifty",
                "comm" => ""
            ),
        "2" => Array (
                "admin" => "1",
                "cid" => "846",
                "phan" => "0",
                "ping" => "30",
                "sec" => "678674",
                "name" => "The1one12",
                "comm" => ""
            )
    ),
    "gq_online" => "0",
    "gq_address" => "172.0.0.1",
    "gq_port" => "3812",
    "gq_prot" => "ventrilo",
    "gq_type" => "ventrilo"
)
```

and I want my end result to be like this:

*cid = Channel ID*

*pid = Parent ID*

```
Array (
"Ventrilo" => Array (
    "name" => "The Evil Teddys",
    "phonetic" => "The Evil Teddys",
    "comment" => "",
    "auth" => "1",
    "maxclients" => "20",
    "voicecodec" => "0,GSM 6.10",
    "voiceformat" => "3,44 KHz, 16 bit",
    "uptime" => "25799604",
    "platform" => "Linux-i386",
    "version" => "3.0.3",
    "channelcount" => "7",
    "teams" => Array (
        "0" => Array (
                "cid" => "846",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "<TET>",
                "comm" => "",
                "players" => Array (
                    "0" => Array (
                            "admin" => "1",
                            "cid" => "846",
                            "phan" => "0",
                            "ping" => "18",
                            "sec" => "345345",
                            "name" => "Shorty*",
                            "comm" => "vet verwacht je niet"
                        ),
                    "1" => Array (
                            "admin" => "1",
                            "cid" => "846",
                            "phan" => "0",
                            "ping" => "30",
                            "sec" => "678674",
                            "name" => "The1one12",
                            "comm" => "grappig !"
                        )
                ),
                "teams" => Array(
                    "0" => Array (
                            "cid" => "849",
                            "pid" => "846",
                            "prot" => "0",
                            "name" => "Foodfightkitchen",
                            "comm" => "",
                            "players" => Array (),
                            "teams" => Array(
                                "0" => Array (
                                        "cid" => "851",
                                        "pid" => "849",
                                        "prot" => "0",
                                        "name" => "Bad Company",
                                        "comm" => "",
                                        "players" => Array (
                                                "0" => Array (
                                                        "admin" => "1",
                                                        "cid" => "851",
                                                        "phan" => "0",
                                                        "ping" => "20",
                                                        "sec" => "11988",
                                                        "name" => "Swifty",
                                                        "comm" => "nu nog Dynamisch"
                                                    )
                                        ),
                                        "teams" => Array(

                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                        ),
                    "1" => Array (
                            "cid" => "850",
                            "pid" => "846",
                            "prot" => "0",
                            "name" => "WOW",
                            "comm" => "",
                            "players" => Array (),
                            "teams" => Array(
                                "0" => Array(
                                        "cid" => "852",
                                        "pid" => "850",
                                        "prot" => "0",
                                        "name" => "The G Channel",
                                        "comm" => "",
                                        "players" => Array (),
                                        "teams" => Array(

                                        )
                                    )
                            )
                        )
                )
            ),
        "1" => Array (
                "cid" => "847",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "#ISOLATIECEL",
                "players" => Array (),
                "teams" => Array(

                )
            ),
        "2" => Array (
                "cid" => "848",
                "pid" => "0",
                "prot" => "0",
                "name" => "Relax Take It Easy",
                "comm" => "",
                "players" => Array (),
                "teams" => Array(

                )
            )
    ),
    "clientcount" => "3",
    "gq_online" => "1",
    "gq_address" => "213.163.76.130",
    "gq_port" => "3812",
    "gq_prot" => "ventrilo",
    "gq_type" => "ventrilo"
)
```

How can I achieve this ? I have tried many things but nothing with this end result.

what i have now.

```
$teamArrayConverted['teams'] = convertTeamArray($serverstatus['teams']);
    unset($serverstatus['players'], $serverstatus['teams']);
$results = array_merge_recursive($serverstatus, $teamArrayConverted);

    function convertTeamArray ($array) {
    // First, convert the array so that the keys match the ids
    $reKeyed = array();
    foreach ($array as $item) {
        $reKeyed[(int) $item['cid']] = $item;
    }
    //print_r($reKeyed);    
    // Next, use references to associate children with parents
    foreach ($reKeyed as $id => $item) {
        if (isset($item['pid'], $reKeyed[(int) $item['pid']])) {
          $reKeyed[(int) $item['pid']]['teams'][] =& $reKeyed[$id];
        }
    }
    //print_r($reKeyed);
    // Finally, go through and remove children from the outer level
    foreach ($reKeyed as $id => $item) {
        if ($item['pid'] != '0') {
          //print_r($reKeyed[$id]);
          unset($reKeyed[$id]);
        }
    }
    return array_values($reKeyed);
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) - Show your code. Nobody is going to write that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in principle like this:

1. You make each node identifiable by it's numeric id and store it in a hash so it's accessible by it's id.
2. You take a new hash and insert all elements incl. their children as needed.

In detail discussion of the code is here: [Converting an array from one to multi-dimensional based on parent ID values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7768445/367456):

```
// key the array by id
$keyed = array();
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    $keyed[$value['id']] = &$value;
}
unset($value);
$array = $keyed;
unset($keyed);

// tree it
$tree = array();
foreach($array as &$value)
{
    if ($parent = $value['parent_id'])
        $array[$parent]['children'][] = &$value;
    else
        $tree[] = &$value;
}
unset($value);
$array = $tree;
unset($tree);

var_dump($array); # your result
```

Replace the names with what you have as variable names and keys.

Comment: i creacted a function with : return array_values($reKeyed);
so its sets the keys in a normal order.

Comment: and now i need to get the players in !

Comment: here is the code working http://theevilteddys.nl/rev91/server

Answer (score 0):

Create an array based on the pid from the current array which you can use to loop through the children based on the id.

```
$arr = array(...definition from your post....);
foreach($arr["teams"] as $team)
    $teamchildren[$team[pid]][]=$team;
print_r($teamchildren);
```

Now you can loop through the $teamchildren[0] array and call a function recursively to build the nested team structure under each of the teams

The same concept could be applied to the players but changing the parent in this case to be the `cid`

(above code is not tested)